# Adding tool tip to collapse graph

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I'm trying to add tooltip to a collapse graph. And i was able to add the tooltip using the mouseon and mouseout event.But the challenge is i am unable to apply my own css on that tool tip .my code is

```
  function mouseover(d) {
d3.select(this).append("text")
    .attr("class", "hover")
    .attr('transform', function(d){ 
        return 'translate(5, -10)';
    })
    .text(d.name + ": " + d.id);
```

}

Comment: It would help folks help you if you were to show more code, so as to give us more context. Even better, you could generate a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a minimal example of what you have so far.

Comment: you can refer this now i want to add css on tool tip how to add plz tell me  http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/6FkBd/2/

Comment: sorry i forget to mention css of hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the necessary css:

```
.hover{
    fill: red;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FkBd/11/).

Comment: that i have already done..i need to add background image and border on the tool tip

Comment: You did not have the css for .hover in your original fiddle. This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/6FkBd/12/) has the beginnings of a more sophisticated tooltip. I hope it helps.

Comment: sorry i forget to mention.Nice! Works great. Thank you!

Comment: Great :-) I am glad the answer helped you.

Comment: @Sumit...also, as part of the SO protocol, please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: i know its very sophisticated tool tip but i like it

Comment: @Sumit I do not understand the problem clearly (you have this as another question). You might want to generate a new question, but this time providing more context and a fiddle with your best efforts so far. This should help you get an answer.

Comment: yes its my another question ..you can refer same example link what ever you have provided. i want to show different time interval along with name.example:name1,system current time -15 min,name2,current time +30 min..like that on each name.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes..Have u got any idea ?

Comment: @Sumit...I won't be able to look at this for a while. I still think you should put a fiddle together, this way others can see and perhaps respond more quickly.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes..How to define different color for each stroke of path linking? i am using this right now  .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.color; }) but i want different color on each link

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/6FkBd/17/) for links with different colors. You can use other color scales...check the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). Also, you should consider asking more in another question...SO discourages long comment threads.